# Using Regex to pull ID specific columns in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe from a tissue slide dataset with the following columns

- Image
- Name
- tumor_stroma_epi_nsclc_v2: Epithelium %
- tumor_stroma_epi_nsclc_v2: Epithelium area Âµm^2
- tumor_stroma_epi_nsclc_v2: Necrosis %
- tumor_stroma_epi_nsclc_v2: Necrosis area Âµm^2
- tumor_stroma_epi_nsclc_v2: Stroma %
- tumor_stroma_epi_nsclc_v2: Stroma area Âµm^2
- tumor_stroma_epi_nsclc_v2: Tumor %
- tumor_stroma_epi_nsclc_v2: Tumor area Âµm^2
- Area Âµm^2

The **nsclc_v2** component of the columns is variable across multiple different datasets depending on the different tissue types. I want to create a regex to drop the % columns that can recognize all columns with the same format, but different tissue types. So far, this is all I was able to come up with.

```
tumor_temp.drop(columns=['Image','Name',
                         '^tumor_stroma_epi_[a-z0-9_]: Epithelium %$',
                         '^tumor_stroma_epi_[a-z0-9_]: Necrosis %$',
                         '^tumor_stroma_epi_[a-z0-9_]: Stroma %$',
                         '^tumor_stroma_epi_[a-z0-9_]: Tumor %$',
                         'Area Âµ?m^2'], inplace=True)
```

Apologies if this is a little basic, I mostly have an R background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `filter()` function from pandas:

```
import re

pattern = re.compile("^tumor_stroma_epi_[a-z0-9_]+:.*%$")  # regular expression to match columns with %
cols_to_drop = df.filter(regex=pattern).columns
df.drop(columns=cols_to_drop, inplace=True)
```